# Is it possible to blanket-toggle changes made through Chrome DevTools?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I know about the Changes drawer, which shows you all the modifications you've made since loading the page, but what I'd love would be to be able to toggle them all off/on to see how the new version looks compared to what was there before.

My current workflow is to load the page up twice, modify one while leaving the other untainted, and switch tabs between them.  It works, but I wonder if there's a toggle in DevTools that I've missed.